# Creating Schema Extension in microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have created an C# application for my organization using azure with all the permission for microsoft graph (including directory.readwrite.all). I am using client id and client secret for authorization.Now I am trying to create a new schema extension but it shows 403 Error.insuffient privileges.

Kindly help me out to do this.

Comment: What resource are you attempting to register a schema extension for?

Comment: u mean target i'm trying to create for "user" @DmitryPimenov

Comment: i'm trying to create a custom column for all my company employees. @DmitryPimenov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client_credentials` flow (no signed-in user) is not supported for schema extension creation/management.  Is there a reason you need to use client credential flow here? The only supported permission (currently per [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/schemaextension_post_schemaextensions)) for schema creation is `User.AccessAsUser.All` delegated permission.  You can also create schema using Graph Explorer, as long as Graph Explorer has been granted the `User.AccessAsUser.All` permission, and you set the `owner` property to the `appId` of your application.

Hope this helps,

Comment: thanks..  @Dan i followed this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions it worked